# TikZ trees grow right typesets things "upside down"

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

This is a pretty minor gripe with what is a great library.

```
\documentclass[border=3em]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right]
  \node {a}
    child {
      node {b}
    }
    child{
      node {c}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This MWE produces the following output:

[image: tree upside down]

Note that despite the `b` node being written before the `c` node, it is the `c` node that is on top. This is unintuitive. I'd have expected the `b` node to be on top, since it's defined first.

I understand why it works that way because without the `grow=right` option, things are typeset in the obvious order. What I want to know is:

> Is there an easy way to have right-growing trees set their nodes in the order you'd expect from reading the source?

---

## Edit

Matthew's suggestion in the comments works well for basic trees. Unfortunately, it breaks the `sloped` option:

```
\documentclass[border=3em]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right,yscale=-1,sloped]
  \node {a}
    child {
      node {b}
      edge from parent
      node[above] {Foo}
    }
    child{
      node {c}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: slope is broke]

Comment: `\node[yscale=-1]` ?

Comment: @Matthew Nope. That turns the node upside down and leaves its children in the wrong order still.

Comment: @Matthew ah, as an option to the `tikzpicture` environment that works. Not as an option on the _node_

Comment: That was why I put the question mark and made it a comment—a stab in the dark to test.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You simply can use the `grow'` option instead: (`pgfmanual` v2.10, p.219)

> This key has the same effect as `grow`, only the children are arranged in the opposite order.

```
\documentclass[border=0,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=right]
  \node {a}
    child {
      node {b}
    }
    child{
      node {c}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: how do you get your standalone images to be bigger? I tried that and they come out really small. I cheated and zoomed in the PDF and took a screen shot of it to get the picture a reasonable size!

Comment: @Seamus: With the current develop version it is `convert={size=<X>x<Y>,...}` or shorter `png={size=<X>x<Y>}`. I also have a `tex.sx` option to set the maximum size of 630px. Everything above is zoomed down on stackexchange.

Comment: @Seamus: helps to be the developer :-P

Comment: and for us mere mortals that have the version on CTAN, when will we get these options? ;)

Comment: @Seamus: Hopefully soon. However, the develop version is available under http://latex.scharrer-online.de/standalone/browser/dev. Also try the "nightly builds" listed on http://latex.scharrer-online.de/standalone.